# How to preserve value of apex:checkbox

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

Visualforce Code

```
<apex:repeat value="{!meetingTypeList}" var="mList" >
<div class="col-lg-4 panel-body2 " >
    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!mList.checkboxfilter}">  
        <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action={!filter}"  >
        </apex:actionSupport>
    </apex:InputCheckBox>
    <apex:outputText value="{!mList.meetType}"/>
 </div>
</apex:repeat>
```

**Controller**

```
 public class wrapperType{
     public string meetType{get;set;}
     public boolean checkboxfilter {get;set;}
     public wrapperType (string meetType){
          this.meetType= meetType;
          this.checkboxfilter =false;
     }
}
```

How can we preserve value of checkbox if we will not use rerender through javascript??

Comment: There could be a thousand issues. You are not showing us how the wrapper is constructed, what the filter method is, what happens on instantiation, etc. Without all of the other code it is tuff to say an exact solution for you. With what you gave us it should be workings what is the issue?

Comment: I can understand that problem...but my main concern is can we preserve value of checkbox after reloading the page without using rerender through javascript ??

Comment: Yes depending on what you mean. You could pass a URL parameter to fetch the values for example. You could use setRedirect=false when going to a new page that uses the same controller, etc. It all depends on your scenario. there is always a way to do it

Comment: public list<wrapperType> valueList{ get; set; }
    public list<wrapperType> getmeetingTypeList(){
            valueList = new List<wrapperType>(); 
            Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Event_Request__c.Meeting_Type__c.getDescribe();
            List<Schema.PicklistEntry> meetingTypeList= fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
            system.debug('hello'+ meetingTypeList );
            for(Schema.PicklistEntry e : meetingTypeList){
                valueList.add(new wrapperType(e.getValue()));
            } 
            return valueList;
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this code:

```
public list<wrapperType> valueList{ get; set; } 
public list<wrapperType> getmeetingTypeList(){ 
    valueList = new List<wrapperType>(); 
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Event_Request__c.Meeting_Type__c.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> meetingTypeList= fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
    system.debug('hello'+ meetingTypeList ); 
    for(Schema.PicklistEntry e : meetingTypeList){ 
        valueList.add(new wrapperType(e.getValue()));
    } 
    return valueList; 
}
```

The problem is that you're re-initializing the wrapper list each time `{!meetingTypeList}` is called (i.e. every time the page reloads), which wipes out your user's values. Instead, consider initializing the list once in your constructor:

```
public MyConstructorName() {
    valueList = new List<wrapperType>(); 
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Event_Request__c.Meeting_Type__c.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> meetingTypeList= fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
    system.debug('hello'+ meetingTypeList ); 
    for(Schema.PicklistEntry e : meetingTypeList){ 
        valueList.add(new wrapperType(e.getValue()));
    } 
}
```

Then, simply use `{!valueList}` directly (alternatively, consider renaming valueList to meetingTypeList instead). This will preserve your user's input across page transactions.

Comment: I have one more issue in my code...if I use Apex:param with support  then i didn't get value in controller...can you tell why??

Comment: @user123 If you were doing it right, it would work. You just need to make sure you're using "assignTo" correctly.

Comment: yes i'm using correctly...but still it show null

Comment: <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!filter}"  >  
    <apex:param name="filterParam" value="{!mList.meetType}" assignto='{!filterParam}" />  
</apex:actionSupport>  


I'm using this function..

public pageReference filter() {  
    string a = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('filterParam');   
    for(wrapperType typo : valueList ){  
        if(typo.checkboxfilter == true ){  
             eventList.add(typo.meetType);  
        }  
    }return null;       
}

Comment: @user123 You don't need to use ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters()... just access filterParam (should be a class variable) directly.

Comment: hmm...I know..but still show null if i use it directly

Comment: My problem is solve out...thank you "sfdcfox" for your solution